# Numpy Vectorize, как производить перебор по столбцам

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется функция, которая производит какие то операции с двумя векторами и возвращает tuple из двух значений:

```
def func(x, y):
    ...
    return res_float1, res_float2
```

Так же имеем массив и вектор, например:

```
x = np.array([[1, 4, 7, -1],
              [2, 5, 8, -2],
              [3, 6, 9, -3]])

y = np.array([[3],
              [3],
              [3]])
```

Необходимо для каждого столбца Х произвести следующее: запихнуть его в func() вместе с У, получить результат в виде кортежа и записать его в строку нового массива. То есть получить что то типа:

```
res = np.array([[func(x[:, 0], y)[0], func(x[:, 0], y)[1]],
                [func(x[:, 1], y)[0], func(x[:, 1], y)[1]],
                [func(x[:, 2], y)[0], func(x[:, 2], y)[1]],
                [func(x[:, 3], y)[0], func(x[:, 3], y)[1]]])
```

Размер массива Х и вектора У заранее, конечно, неизвестен
Можно, конечно, циклом по каждому столбцу пройти, но массивы могут быть огромными, не хочется цикл городить. Я подумал, что функция np.vectorize() может помочь. Но, судя по выводу, она похоже применяет оригинальную функцию не к каждому столбцу, а к каждому элементу.

Comment: Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Дописал вопрос. Спасибо)

Comment: вам много что может дать, если заменить вызов функции на операции numpy, а так как у вас изложено, можно оставить просто цикл

Comment: Мало что понятно о конечном массиве... Но предполагаю, что вам поможет в его сборке numpy.stack